# How to use merge and concat in one function?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two tables -

[image]

and want to get the following one

[image]

I managed to do so with the following code:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]),
                   columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2,8], [4, 6,20]]),
                   columns=['a', 'b','d'])
df = pd.concat([df1[['a','b','d']],df2[['a','b']]])
new = (df.sort_values(['a','b','d'],ascending=False).drop_duplicates(['a']))
print(pd.merge(new,df2[['a','c']],how='outer', on=['a']))
```

But I wonder is there an easier code, which would lead to the same results in one step e.g.?

Answer (score 0):

So in your case just need `concat` then `groupby` with `ffill` and `bfill`

```
out = pd.concat([df1,df2]).groupby(['a']).apply(lambda x : x.ffill().bfill()).\
              sort_values(['a','b','d'],ascending=False).drop_duplicates(['a'])
   a  b     d    c
2  7  8   NaN  9.0
1  4  6  20.0  6.0
0  1  2   8.0  3.0
```